# Update matching values from 2 workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks and I need to cross reference the policy number from the 2 spreadsheets (policy number in column C for both).  If a matching policy number is found, I would like to copy and paste the data located in column A from workbook 2 over to workbook 1, column Y. I was hoping to get VBA code written for this as I have big datasets to be consolidated from several Excel spreadsheets, and it takes too much time to complete the following via VLOOKUPs.

ive come up with this much code and there seems to be an error "object not found"
im just learning how to code now so im not sure where i went wrong

```
Sub transfer()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrowl As Long, lastrow2 As Long

Dim policyID As String
lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
policyID = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i, "C").Value

Sheets("MAE Project").Activate
lastrow2 = Sheets("MAE Project").Range("B" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow2

If Sheets("MAE Project").Cells(j, "B").Value = policy Then
Sheets("sheet2").Activate
Sheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(i, "A")).Copy
Sheets("MAE Project").Activate
Sheets("MAE Project").Range(Cells(j, "Y")).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
Sheets("sheet2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to be make your question clearer. If you have code that isn't working for you, then please include it so we can help you. If "I was hoping to get a VBA code written for this" is asking for recommendations of a VBA developer to assist you, then I suspect you've come to the wrong site (there are plenty of VBA freelancer finding sites that can assist you, though).